# How to save the customize columns in many to many relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two table which is jobseekers and jobpositions.They are many to many relationship, so in jobseekers model, I put the relationship like this.

```
public function My_jobpositions(){
  return $this->belongsToMany("App\Models\Jobposition",'jobposition_jobseeker','jobseeker_id','jobposition_id')->withPivot('stage', 'status','interview_time')
     ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Here is the jobposition_jobseeker table look like 
[image]
and when I try to save in (jobposition_jobseeker) table in controller, its only save the id of the row from jobseeker table instead of jobseeker_id in jobposition_jobseeker table, but i have another columns beside id which is jobseeker_id in jobseeker table, I just want to store the jobseeker_id , don't want to store the id of the row from jobseekers table in jobposition_jobseeker table.

```
  $jobposition = Jobseeker::find(Input::get('jobseeker_id'));          
   $jobposition->My_jobpositions()->attach(Jobposition::find($value),['stage' => $stage[$index],'status'=>$status[$index],'interview_time'=>$interview_time[$index]]);
```

This is the jobseeker table look like.
[image]

Can anyone guide me please, anyhelp would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did u try using [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Jobposition",'jobposition_jobseeker','jobseeker_id','jobposition_id')->withPivot('stage', 'status','interview_time')
 ->withTimestamps();`
```